# very beginner jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-frontend

I am brand new to jQuery, I'm proficient in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I've set up a little test form and I just need help getting the ball rolling. I'm trying to add the class of 'form-control' to all my inputs on the page and I can't seem to figure it out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').addClass('form-control');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-floating">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 form-floating">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 form-floating">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" id="phone">
      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 form-floating">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just add that class to the input elements in the HTML? And your code works, btw, as you can see from the snippet I added. Just "inspect" on each input and you'll see they all have "form-control" classes.

Comment: Yes! At work, we connect our front-end to Netsuite. Unfortunately, Netsuite makes it's own inputs and in order to target them, we have to use JavaScript or jQuery to do so.

Comment: Removed and "fixed" by the edit: **Here is the CDN that I'm using `<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`"* - that's not a CDN link, make sure you use a full path such as `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

Add this script to the head on document

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it should work, and check chrome devtools if you have other errors.

Comment: OP's example already uses jQuery 3.3.1. It's not clear why you would advise version 1.7.1.

Comment: @freedomn-m I see the edit on OPs post. Must have come in before I commented.